# add characters each two places within sed

Tags: regex, csv, sed

I am working with csv files, they seismic catalogs from a database, I need to arrange them like USGS format in order to start another steps.

My input data format is:

```
DatesT,Latitude,Longitude,Magnitude,Depth,Catalog
1909,7,23,170000,-17.430,-66.349,5.1,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
1913,12,14,024500,-17.780,-63.170,5.6,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
```

The USGS input format is

```
DatesT,Latitude,Longitude,Magnitude,Depth,Catalog
1909-7-23T17:00:00,-17.430,-66.349,5.1,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
1913-12-14T02:45:00,-17.780,-63.170,5.6,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
```

To "convert" my input to USGS format I did the following steps:

```
archi='catalog.txt'
sed 's/,/-/1' $archi > temp1.dat   # to change "," to "-" 
sed 's/,/-/1' temp1.dat > temp2.dat  # same as above
sed 's/,/T/1' temp2.dat > temp3.dat   # To add T between date and time
sed -i.bak "1 s/^.*$/DatesT,Latitude,Longitude,Magnitude,Depth,Catalog/" temp3.dat  #to preserve the header.
```

I have the following output:

```
DatesT,Latitude,Longitude,Magnitude,Depth,Catalog
1909-7-23T170000,-17.430,-66.349,5.1,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
1913-12-14T024500,-17.780,-63.170,5.6,0,PRE-GEM-ISC
```

I tried to implement the following command:

```
sed 's/.\{13\}/&: /g' temp3.dat > temp4.dat
```

Unfortunately it did not work as I thought because it did not have the same place for all lines.

Do you have any idea to improve my code?

Comment: Do your actual files have those header lines?

Comment: @Shawn, yes they have those headers

Answer (score 3):

One way using GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{1,2}),([0-9]{1,2}),([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(,.*)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6\7/'  file
```

You split the file into individual tokens,meaning column as token one, 2nd column as token 2, and when it comes to 4th column, take 2 numbers as a token, and then substitute it as required.

Comment: the clarification of tokens are properly in this case, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
cat initialfile.csv|perl -p -e "s/^(\d{4}),(\d+),(\d+),(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}),([0-9.-]+),([0-9.-]+),(.*)$/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6,\7,\8,\9/g"
```

or for inline edit:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/^(\d{4}),(\d+),(\d+),(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}),([0-9.-]+),([0-9.-]+),(.*)$/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6,\7,\8,\9/g" initialfile.csv
```

which should output USGS format

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E  '1!s/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:/' file
```

Forget about the header.

Replace the first and second fields delimiters (all fields are delimited by a comma `,`) with a dash `-`.

Replace the third fields delimiter by `T`.

Split the fourth field into three equal parts and separate each part by a colon `:`.

N.B. The last part of the fourth field will stay as is and so does not need to be defined.

Sometimes as programmers we become too focused on data and would be better served by looking at the problem as an artist and coding what we see.